# Win32 API to get Machine UUID

Tags: winapi, uuid, bios

I am looking to retrieve the UUID of a machine.

I want the equivalent of this, but using the Win32 API instead:

> wmic csproduct get "UUID"

I don't want a dependency on WMI.

Comment: Do you mind sharing why you don't take dependency on WMI? Maybe you can get UUID programmatically (depending on [wbemuuid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/setting-the-security-levels-on-a-wmi-connection) library).

Comment: generate random uuid yourself and save it, than take from place where you save it

Comment: AFAIK, there is no Win32 API to get the machine UUID, unless you can find it in the Registry somewhere. The WMI [`Win32_ComputerSystemProduct`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-computersystemproduct) documentation says the UUID "comes from the UUID member of the **System Information** structure in the SMBIOS information" and there is no Win32 API to read BIOS data, but there are WMI classes for that. Universal apps can use [`GetSystemFirmwareTable()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemfirmwaretable), though.

Comment: @RemyLebeau [GetSystemFirmwareTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemfirmwaretable) is a Win32 API (which can be used by both Win32 and UWP apps).

Answer (score 8):

Here's the code example:(Use [GetSystemFirmwareTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemfirmwaretable))

> GetSystemFirmwareTable: Retrieves the specified firmware table from
>   the firmware table provider.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <tchar.h>


typedef struct _dmi_header
{
    BYTE type;
    BYTE length;
    WORD handle;
}dmi_header;



typedef struct _RawSMBIOSData
{
    BYTE    Used20CallingMethod;
    BYTE    SMBIOSMajorVersion;
    BYTE    SMBIOSMinorVersion;
    BYTE    DmiRevision;
    DWORD   Length;
    BYTE    SMBIOSTableData[];
}RawSMBIOSData;


static void dmi_system_uuid(const BYTE *p, short ver)
{
    int only0xFF = 1, only0x00 = 1;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 16 && (only0x00 || only0xFF); i++)
    {
        if (p[i] != 0x00) only0x00 = 0;
        if (p[i] != 0xFF) only0xFF = 0;
    }



    if (only0xFF)
    {
        printf("Not Present");
        return;
    }

    if (only0x00)
    {
        printf("Not Settable");
        return;
    }


    if (ver >= 0x0206)
        printf("%02X%02X%02X%02X-%02X%02X-%02X%02X-%02X%02X-%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X\n",
            p[3], p[2], p[1], p[0], p[5], p[4], p[7], p[6],
            p[8], p[9], p[10], p[11], p[12], p[13], p[14], p[15]);
    else
        printf("-%02X%02X%02X%02X-%02X%02X-%02X%02X-%02X%02X-%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X\n",
            p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4], p[5], p[6], p[7],
            p[8], p[9], p[10], p[11], p[12], p[13], p[14], p[15]);
}


const char *dmi_string(const dmi_header *dm, BYTE s)
{
    char *bp = (char *)dm;
    size_t i, len;

    if (s == 0)
        return "Not Specified";

    bp += dm->length;

    while (s > 1 && *bp)
    {
        bp += strlen(bp);
        bp++;
        s--;
    }
    if (!*bp)
        return "BAD_INDEX";

    /* ASCII filtering */
    len = strlen(bp);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        if (bp[i] < 32 || bp[i] == 127)
            bp[i] = '.';
    return bp;
}



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DWORD bufsize = 0;
    BYTE buf[65536] = { 0 };
    int ret = 0;
    RawSMBIOSData *Smbios;
    dmi_header *h = NULL;
    int flag = 1;

    ret = GetSystemFirmwareTable('RSMB', 0, 0, 0);
    if (!ret)
    {
        printf("Function failed!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("get buffer size is %d\n", ret);
    bufsize = ret;

    ret = GetSystemFirmwareTable('RSMB', 0, buf, bufsize);

    if (!ret)
    {
        printf("Function failed!\n");
        return 1;
    }



    Smbios = (RawSMBIOSData *)buf;
    BYTE *p = Smbios->SMBIOSTableData;

    if (Smbios->Length != bufsize - 8)
    {
        printf("Smbios length error\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < Smbios->Length; i++) {
        h = (dmi_header *)p;

        if (h->type == 0 && flag) {
            printf("\nType %02d - [BIOS]\n", h->type);
            printf("\tBIOS Vendor : %s\n", dmi_string(h, p[0x4]));
            printf("\tBIOS Version: %s\n", dmi_string(h, p[0x5]));
            printf("\tRelease Date: %s\n", dmi_string(h, p[0x8]));

            if (p[0x16] != 0xff && p[0x17] != 0xff)
                printf("\tEC version: %d.%d\n", p[0x16], p[0x17]);
            flag = 0;
        }



        else if (h->type == 1) {
            printf("\nType %02d - [System Information]\n", h->type);
            printf("\tManufacturer: %s\n", dmi_string(h, p[0x4]));
            printf("\tProduct Name: %s\n", dmi_string(h, p[0x5]));
            printf("\tVersion: %s\n", dmi_string(h, p[0x6]));
            printf("\tSerial Number: %s\n", dmi_string(h, p[0x7]));
            printf("\tUUID: "); dmi_system_uuid(p + 0x8, Smbios->SMBIOSMajorVersion * 0x100 + Smbios->SMBIOSMinorVersion);
            printf("\tSKU Number: %s\n", dmi_string(h, p[0x19]));
            printf("\tFamily: %s\n", dmi_string(h, p[0x1a]));
        }
        p += h->length;
        while ((*(WORD *)p) != 0) p++;
        p += 2;
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Machine UUID is defined by SMBIOS v2.1+ (System Management BIOS (SMBIOS)) in the System Information (Type 1) structure.

Although you can retrieve raw SMBIOS data using [GetSystemFirmwareTable()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemfirmwaretable), the Windows SMBIOS driver actually writes most of the Type 1 defined values in the registry under `HKLM\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\BIOS\ComputerHardwareId`.

Simply reading the registry value will give you the Machine UUID without bothering going through the raw SMBIOS data.

Here is snippet of a Win32 function that should just retrieve the Machine's UUID. (untested)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winerror.h>
static HRESULT GetMachineUUID(
        /* [out] */ WCHAR **ppszMachineUUID)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    LPWSTR pszMachineUUID = NULL;
    DWORD cbMachineUUID = 0;
    DWORD cchMachineUUID = 0;
    LONG lResult = ERROR_SUCCESS;

    lResult = RegGetValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                L"HARDWARE\\DESCRIPTION\\System\\BIOS",
                L"ComputerHardwareId",
                RRF_RT_REG_SZ, NULL,
                pszMachineUUID,
                &cbMachineUUID);

    if (ERROR_MORE_DATA == lResult || ERROR_SUCCESS == lResult)
    {
        cchMachineUUID = (cbMachineUUID / sizeof(WCHAR));

        pszMachineUUID = SysAllocStringLen(NULL, cchMachineUUID);

        if (pszMachineUUID == NULL)
        {
            hr = E_OUTOFMEMORY;
            goto Error;
        }

        lResult = RegGetValue(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,
                    bstrNodeName,
                    sc_szV2CSPNodePathRegValueName,
                    RRF_RT_REG_SZ,
                    NULL,
                    pszMachineUUID,
                    &cbMachineUUID);

        hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(lResult);

        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            goto Error;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(lResult);

        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            goto Error;
        }
    }

    *ppszMachineUUID = pszMachineUUID;
    pszMachineUUID = NULL;

Error:
    SysFreeString(pszMachineUUID);
    return hr;
}
```

I havn't tested the code above, but it should work.

See the latest SMBIOS reference specification posted at https://www.dmtf.org/standards/smbios

Comment: on my machine (win7 x64 ultimate) there is no ComputerHardwareId value in the registry key you indicated (despite such UUID can be read without problems from the raw smbios table and with a much simpler and shorter code)

Answer (score 0):

Based on Strive Sun's code, I created one header library that allows you to get uuid into supplied buffer:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "system-uuid.h"


typedef struct _dmi_header
{
    BYTE type;
    BYTE length;
    WORD handle;
}dmi_header;


typedef struct _RawSMBIOSData
{
    BYTE    Used20CallingMethod;
    BYTE    SMBIOSMajorVersion;
    BYTE    SMBIOSMinorVersion;
    BYTE    DmiRevision;
    DWORD   Length;
    BYTE    SMBIOSTableData[];
}RawSMBIOSData;


static int format_system_uuid(const BYTE *p, int ver, char *buf, int size)
{
    if (ver >= 0x0206){
        return snprintf(buf, size,
                        "%02X%02X%02X%02X-%02X%02X-%02X%02X-%02X%02X-%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
                        p[3], p[2], p[1], p[0], p[5], p[4], p[7], p[6],
                        p[8], p[9], p[10], p[11], p[12], p[13], p[14], p[15]);
    }
    else{
        return snprintf(buf, size,
                        "%02X%02X%02X%02X-%02X%02X-%02X%02X-%02X%02X-%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
                        p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4], p[5], p[6], p[7],
                        p[8], p[9], p[10], p[11], p[12], p[13], p[14], p[15]);
    }
}


char* get_system_uuid(char *out_buf, int size){
    int bufsize = 0;
    BYTE bios_buf[65536] = { 0 };
    RawSMBIOSData *Smbios = (RawSMBIOSData *)bios_buf;

    bufsize = GetSystemFirmwareTable('RSMB', 0, 0, 0);
    if (!bufsize)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    if(!GetSystemFirmwareTable('RSMB', 0, Smbios, bufsize)){
        return NULL;
    }
    if (Smbios->Length != bufsize - 8)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    BYTE *raw_smbios_ptr = (BYTE *)Smbios->SMBIOSTableData;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Smbios->Length; i++){
        dmi_header *header_ptr = (dmi_header *)raw_smbios_ptr;

        if (header_ptr->type == 1){
            int formatted_len = format_system_uuid(raw_smbios_ptr + 0x8,
                                                   Smbios->SMBIOSMajorVersion * 0x100 + Smbios->SMBIOSMinorVersion,
                                                   out_buf,
                                                   size);
            return out_buf;
        }

        raw_smbios_ptr += header_ptr->length;
        while (*(WORD *)raw_smbios_ptr != 0){
            raw_smbios_ptr++;
        }
        raw_smbios_ptr += 2;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```